# do.call returns single value from list of arguments - expecting multiple values

Tags: r, curl, do.call

I have a function called "block" which uses the CURL package to retrieve information from a web API. The function takes two arguments ("latty" and "longy") and I'd like to use do.call to pass a list of values for the arguments.

However, it only seems to be passing the first pair of values and it doesn't move on to the next pair.

Here is my code:

```
block <- function(latty, longy){
   Sys.sleep(0.25)
   url <- paste0("https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/block/find?latitude=", 
          latty, "&longitude=", longy)
   response <- curl(url)
   data <- readLines(response, warn=FALSE)
   blockID <- substr(sub(".*Block FIPS=\\\"","",data), 0, 15)
   return(blockID)
   }

result <- do.call(block, list(latty=latlngVA$LATITUDE, longy=latlngVA$LONGITUDE))
```

Thank you!

Comment: you might be confusing `do.call` with `Map`

Comment: would `Map(block,latty=latlngVA$LATITUDE, longy=latlngVA$LONGITUDE)` or `mapply(block,latty=latlngVA$LATITUDE, longy=latlngVA$LONGITUDE)` give you what you want ?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks so much, this is super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're confusing `do.call` with `Map`. `do.call` is used to provide to a function its arguments stored in a list. `Map` is used to call a function several time on lists of arguments element by element in parallel.

Here's what should work for you:

```
Map(block,latty=latlngVA$LATITUDE, longy=latlngVA$LONGITUDE)
```